# Jquery help: .click() to each individual element

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, each

I've written up this code to add a class (`.box-open` which adds display:block) to my box (`.sharebox`) when a button (`#share-but`) is clicked but the problem is I'm having trouble making this only apply to one .share div at a time because everytime I click a button, all the `.sharebox`s get the class `.box-open` applied to it.

```
function shareBox() {
$('.share').each(function( index ) {
    $(this).on('click', '#share-but', function() {
        if ($('.sharebox').hasClass('box-open')) {
            $('.sharebox').removeClass('box-open');
        }        
        else {
            $('.sharebox').addClass('box-open');
        }
    });
});
}
shareBox();
```

Here is an image of the problem (I'm building a Tumblr Theme). Hopefully it's a lot easier to understand. http://24.media.tumblr.com/c5c4252607bf4a9905c7c9de5b592c60/tumblr_ml4t2fSuQo1rqce8co1_500.png <---- This happened when I clicked one of the buttons, but I only want one `.sharebox` to have the class `.box-open` added to it when I click the `#share-but` inside the same `.share` div.

I hope all of this made sense. I'm still very noob at Javascript/Jquery as I only started learning like 2 weeks ago so any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `$(this)` instead of `$('.sharebox')` to address source of event

```
$('.sharebox').addClass('box-open');
```

Would be

```
$(this).addClass('box-open');
```

The id of element is supposed to be **unique** in document so you can bind click directly to '#share-but', if it is not unique you can bind it like this.

```
$('.share').on('click', '#share-but', function() {
    if ($('.sharebox').hasClass('box-open')) {
        $('.sharebox').removeClass('box-open');
    }        
    else {
        $('.sharebox').addClass('box-open');
    }
});
```

You can use `toggleClass` to make it simple, I assume you have single item with id #share-but,

```
$('#share-but').click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass("box-open");
});
```

Comment: second should be ``$(this).addClass('box-open');``

Comment: Thanks @doniyor, so nice of you.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a simpler version, you can toggle the classname :)

```
   $('.share').on("click", "#share-but", function() {
      $(this).find(".sharebox").toggleClass('box-open');
  });
```